# Optionals and mapping actions

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

I have the following case that I seem to not understand how I should handle it correctly.

Suppose the following domain structure. I have a customer object which store a list of contacts objects.

Now I want to do the following:

1) Attempt to retrieve the said customer (an optional).

2) If it exists use it to retrieve a contact object.

My code at the time being looks like so:

```
Contact contact = customer.map(cust -> getContacts().stream()
                                                    .findFirst()
                                                    .orElse(null))
                          .orElse(null);
```

Note that the customer object has been initialized as a Optional. Now my question is the following:

I would like to get rid of the `orElse` statements in order to streamline the code and have simply return true or false based on whether the object in question equals to another. I have tried this so far, which I think will do the job.

```
return customer.map(cust -> getContacts()
                            .stream()
                            .findFirst()
                            .map(custContact -> custContact.map(contact::equals).orElse(false))
                            .orElse(false);
```

My main question is, can this be streamlined even more? I think I'm missing something in those mapping actions but I'm not really sure.

My other solution is this one:

```
return customer.map(cust -> getContacts()
                           .stream()
                           .findFirst()
                           .map(contact::equals).orElse(false))
                           .orElse(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Optional.filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) with [`Stream.anyMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [`Optional.isPresent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--):

```
customer.filter(cust -> getContacts().stream().anyMatch(contact::equals)).isPresent();
```